# split string with regex lookaround in Js

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have tricky problem. I need to split the following string at `.` followed by a word:

`".use(z.string().min(2).max(4)).array(.length())"`

But the thing is, that I only need to split on `.use(...)` and `.array(...)` and the content between the braces should be untouched.

Currently I use a positive lookahead to match on `.` followed by a word

`/(?=\.[\w]+)/`

but, obviously, this also splits the string inside the braces.

I thought about building a lookaround pattern that checks if the matches are inside braces but my regex knowledge is not that good so I don't really know where/how to start.

I'd appreciate any hints in the right direction.

Comment: Balancing parentheses in regex is not a trivial thing to do. This looks like an XY problem. What are you actually trying to do ? Process some kind of database function ?

Comment: @Titus I use this in my prisma generator for parsing the informtion that is annotated in the rich-comments - see here: https://github.com/chrishoermann/zod-prisma-types#field-validators 

I split the strings to validate if the used annotation is valid and to later extract the string inside the braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Track how deep into nested brackets you are, so that you can decide when to split only when you are not within nested brackets.

```js
const s = ".use(z.string().min(2).max(4)).array(.length())";

let splitIndices = [0];
let depth = 0;
[...s].forEach((c,i) => {
  if(!depth && !c.match(/\w/)) {
    let p = s.substring(0, i-1).match(/\.\w+$/)?.index;
    if(p) splitIndices.push(p);
  }
  if(c==='(') depth++;
  if(c===')') depth--;
})
console.log(splitIndices.map((e,i,a)=>s.substring(e, a[i+1])))
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly. I was so fixed on using a regex that I didn't think about a different approach.